# Adding additional infomation to Python Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

Python noob question that's not easy to Google.  Coming from C++ I'm still coming to grips with what can be done in Python.

I want to raise an exception in Python and add a number and string value to the exception.  The exception must be a standard Python exception, not a custom one.  I was planning on using RuntimeError.

So, can I add a number and string value to RuntimeError?

(Edit: Why don't I just use a custom exception?  I tried!  See [Python: Referring to an Exception Class Created with PyErr_NewException in an Extension Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916572/python-referring-to-an-exception-class-created-with-pyerr-newexception-in-an-ex))

Comment: I feel like it could be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157210/how-do-i-raise-the-same-exception-with-a-custom-message-in-python

Comment: You can subclass Exception class for your own types of exceptions, where you can add any additional information.

Comment: @sashkello I don't think it's a duplicate of that question because that question just uses a string.  I think the exception classes usually accept a string as part of their definition.  I am asking about adding arbitrary extra data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and it will be stored in the `args` attribute

```
>>> try: 
...     raise RuntimeError('test', 5)
... except Exception as e:
...     print e.args
...
('test', 5)
```

I would think twice about your restriction against creating your own exception type; proper exception types are extremely important.

Answer (score 1):

The initializer for RuntimeError takes an arbitrary set of arguments. Like this:

```
if temp < 0:
    raise RuntimeError(temp, "Wicked Cold")
```